# Using React Javascript (Form-Onsubmit & calling API not working properly)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api, async-await

i am a bit puzzled with the logic when reading the below code, although the code is working but not exactly as i would like it to behave.

3 queries  i have if some one can please clarify.

1-  As i understand useEffect is used to invoke the function after render, but in the below code, once the form is sumbitted (onSubmit={credentialVerify}) it will call the credentialVerify() function as below, so i dont think we need useEffect here, but still the code doesnt call the API unless i use the useEffect statement.

2- Also doesnt wait for me to enter my credentails first and as soon as i go to the Signin page it will fetch the API’s (when using useEffect ) and shows the result in the windows, but i try to design in a way that when i click button then it will fetch the API

3- when in the form onsubmit call the credentialVerify function, i have console.log(e) but it is showing as undefined, but as i understand onsubmit will call the function and through the event argument by default.

Below is the snippet of my code.

Any help Appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import "../App.css";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    function Signin() {
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
      const updateName = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value);
      };
      const updatePassword = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value);
      };
      const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
      useEffect(() => {              //Point-1  useEffect- API not call atall without this statement
        credentialVerify();
      }, []);
      const credentialVerify = async (e) => {
        console.log(e);                                         //Point-3 this is coming as undefined
        const data1 = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/customers");
        const incomingdata = await data1.json();
        console.log(data1);
        console.log(incomingdata);
        console.log(name, password);
        setItems(incomingdata);
      };
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            {
              <form className="formstyle" onSubmit={credentialVerify}>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Username"
                  name="username"
                  value={name}
                  onChange={updateName}
                />
                          
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  name="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={updatePassword}
                />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
              </form>
            }
          </div>
          <div>
           
            {items.map((entry) => {
              let key = entry.email;
              let valuefirst = entry.firstName;
              let valuelast = entry.created_at;
            
              return (
                <p key={key}>
                  {key}: {valuefirst}bb {valuelast}
                </p>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    export default Signin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your **first** question, you are correct - it doesn't make sense to call `credentialVerify` when your component renders for the first time  since that seems to be the handler for when your form gets submitted. Unless you're fetching data prior to displaying your form, you can drop the `useEffect` hook entirely.

This is also takes care of your **second** question because the hook will run once when your component renders for the first time, which is indicated by the empty array `[]` used as a dependency array of the `useEffect` hook. This is equivalent to `componentDidMount` in a `class-based` component, but again, it doesn't make sense to call `credentialVerify` at this point.

As for your **third** question, you should probably do something like the following:

```js
const credentialVerify = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  (async () => {
    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/customers")
      .then(res => res.json());
      .catch(e => e);
    console.log(incomingData);
    // ...
  })();
}
```

Since you're passing an asynchronous function as your event handler, you might have issues accessing the `SyntheticEvent` object due to the reasons stated in `React` docs:

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

- [reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

---

Your final component should look like the following:

```
function Signin() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const updateName = e => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };
  const updatePassword = e => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };
  const credentialVerify = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    (async () => {
      const incomingdata = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/customers")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(e => e);
      console.log(incomingdata);
      console.log(name, password);
      setItems(incomingdata);
    })();
  };
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @goti1 yes it makes sense now and now the code is working too. Thanks alot :)